# The limit is that which is neither too big nor too small to be the limit.

Tags: limits, reference-request, epsilon-delta

**Proposed definition:**
$$
\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = L
$$
means $L$ is the only number that is neither too big nor too small to be the limit.  This can make sense only if one says precisely what "too big" and "too small" mean.  Is there some published definition that does that and that is simpler than the usual $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition (but logically equivalent to it)?

Comment: That sounds really imprecise.  Can *you* expand on what you mean by "too big" and "too small"?

Comment: Nice question, with its echoing of wording used by Archimedes (and possibly earlier mathematicians).

Comment: Do you mean hyperreal?

Comment: I'm confused by the wording.  To me, it seems like the definition you give after the word "means" is basically explaining the $=$ sign.  In your definition, you already use the word limit, so it seems like this definition isn't the definition of a limit, because otherwise the definition would be recursive.  Am I making any sense?

Comment: I think the quanitification of "too big/small" is really the crux of what the definition of a limit is.  The epsilon-delta definition defines it with $|f(x)-L|\lt \epsilon$ and the neighborhood definition with $f(N(\delta, a)) \subset N(\epsilon,L)$.  Leaving the most crucial part of the definition out doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Partly the question was inspired by a definition of "derivative" as the only number that is neither too big nor too small to be the derivative.  Suppose for every function $\ell$ whose graph is a straight line passing through $(a,f(a))$ with slope more than $m$ we have $f(x)>\ell(x)$ for $x<a$ and $f(x)<\ell(x)$ for $x>a$, all this for $x$ sufficiently close to $a$.  Then $m$ is not too big to be the derivative.  Define "not to small" analogously. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Also, the Lebesgue integral of a non-negative function is essentially defined as the smallest number that is not too small.  It's too small if it's smaller than the integral of some simple function (i.e. function with only finitely many values) that is dominated by the function being integrated.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest number that is not too big to be the limit is one way to describe the limit superior, $\limsup_{x\to a}f(x)$, and the smallest number that is not too small to be the limit is one way to describe the limit inferior, $\liminf_{x\to a}f(x)$. Any number $l\in[\liminf,\limsup]$ is a number that is neither too big nor too small to be the limit. And if $\liminf=\limsup$, then there is only one such number, the limit $L$.

Some references that turned up on Google Books for this approach, at least for limits of sequences:

Bartle "The elements of integration and Lebesgue measure"

> If the limit inferior and the limit superior are equal, then their value is called the **limit** of the sequence. It is clear that this agrees with the conventional definition when the sequence and the limit belong to $\mathbf R$.

Edgar "Classics on Fractals"

> If the limit inferior $\underline\alpha$ and the limit superior $\overline\alpha$ coincide, then it is appropriate to speak of the convergence of the sequence and to introduce the notation $\lim A_n = \alpha$.

Sikorski "Advanced calculus: Functions of several variables"

> If the limit superior and the limit inferior are equal, their common values $a$ is called the *limit* of $(a_n)$ and denoted by $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n$.

Thielman "Theory of functions of real variables"

> If the limit superior of a sequence $\{S_n\}$ of sets is the same set as the limit inferior of the sequence of sets, this set is called the *limit of the sequence* $\{S_n\}$ of sets, and it is denoted by $\lim_{n\to\infty}S_n$ or simply by $\lim S_n$.

Comment: I'm not at all convinced that this is simpler than the usual $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition.  See my comment under the question. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Well, it has its advantages. One can talk about liminfs and limsups without uttering the phrase "if it exists" every ten seconds, which is a form of simplicity. :)